# Math.sin() does not give accurate results [I'm using Math.toRadians to pass the right values]

Tags: android

I'm actually using Math.sin() in my android app to calculate a sinus of a given angle (using Math.toRadians(angle_in_degrees)). For exemple when I want to get the Math.cos(90) which is 0, the result is 6.123233... E-17. Thanks you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. The result is well within the accuracy provided by double. See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For floating point numbers, the system can often only approximate their values. For instance, the system would return something like 0.333333 for the expression (1.0 / 3). The number of 3s after the decimal point will be different depending on  whether you're a floats or doubles, but it will still be limited to some finite length.

If you're just displaying the value, then you can limit the number of digits using something like `String.format("%0.2f", value)` or by rounding it using one of the rounding functions such as `Math.round()`.

The tricky part comes when you need to compare the value to something. You can't just use `if (value == some_constant)` or even `if (value == some_variable)`. At minimum, you usually have to use something like `if (Math.abs(value - some_constant) < 0.001)`. The actual value of the '0.001' depends on the needs of your particular application and is customarily defined as a named constant.

For more complicated needs, you can implement the algorithm in the [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting back an approximation from Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) which is

6.123233... E-17 == 0.00000000000000006123233... which is basically 0

The following link should help clear things up as far as the precision of doubles/floats in programming.
http://www.java67.com/2015/09/float-and-double-value-comparison-in-java-use-relational.html